# Show attribute description when filtering by that attribute

Tags: customization, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I’m setting up a woocommerce shop for my wife. In this shop, the brands mean a lot to us so we’ve added descriptions for each brand. A nice little story with an image and everything. Now when I click the brand-attribute from a single product page, I go to http://www.webshop.com/brand/brand-attribute which show the description above some products.

Is there a way to make this work with filters as well? So I’m in the shop and when I filter on brand X, that the description of brand X will appear on the page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to check when filter is enabled and take selected attribute taxonomy, 'pa_brand' in this case:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'desc_before', 75 ); 

function desc_before() {
    if (is_filtered()) { 
        $brands = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes() ['pa_brand'];
        if ( isset($brands) ) { 
            foreach ($brands['terms'] as $term ) {
                $term_obj  = get_term_by('slug', $term, 'pa_brand');

                echo '<div class="ka-attr-description">'.
                     '<h4>' . $term_obj ->name . '</h4>'.
                     $term_obj->description.
                     '</div>';
            } 
        }
    }
}
```