# Conditional for product attribute page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Setup - the WooCommerce main "Shop" page with a "Filter Products By Attribute" (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/#section-6) sidebar widget.

When I select an attribute, the page displays products accordingly (/shop/?filter_name=filter_type).

i want a check for when the page is showing a filtered list of products, i.e.

```
if (shop_page_is_showing_filtered())

// 

elseif (is_shop())

//
```

Something like this is good - [Show attribute description when filtering by that attribute](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289388/show-attribute-description-when-filtering-by-that-attribute) - but it requires explicitly stating the attribute. I just want to know if my page is showing ANY attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
function active_woocommerce_filters() {

    // for older WC versions
    // global $_chosen_attributes;

    $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();

    return count( $_chosen_attributes );

}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229238/woocommerce-check-if-filtering-products